# How should I manage platform specific code in my Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cross-platform, code-organization

I'm writing a gem that will have a platform specific (OSX, Windows and Linux) portion, as well as a platform independent portion. Each platform specific section will probably also depend on other platform specific gems.

I'm not very sure how to organize this.

Should I write a shared gem for the platform independent part, then three gems for the platform specific parts, and specify the shared gem as a dependency for each of them?

Or is there a clever way to use the platform to set the (platform specific) dependencies in my gemspec?

Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably sound like a cop-out answer, but it really depends on the gem and its internals. I would say it would make a decent amount of sense to have, in your main `require` file, logic that requires the platform-specific files for your gem based on the platform. For example:

```
# a user requires your library
require 'that_awesome_gem'

# in your gem's lib/that_awesome_gem.rb
if PLATFORM.os_x? # or whatever
  require 'that_awesome_gem/os_x/module1'
  require 'that_awesome_gem/os_x/module2'
elsif PLATFORM.win?
  require 'that_awesome_gem/win/module1'
  require 'that_awesome_gem/win/module2'
end
```

You could also allow the user to specify which version they want via their require statement.

```
# lib/that_awesome_gem/os_x.rb
PLATFORM.set_manual(:os_x)
require 'that_awesome_gem'

# lib/that_awesome_gem/win.rb
PLATFORM.set_manual(:win)
require 'that_awesome_gem'

# in the user's app
require 'that_awesome_gem/os_x'
```

(Note: obviously defining a global constant in your app isn't a great idea, but you get the general idea. :)

Comment: The last piece of code with `Gem::Specification.new` is a common misunderstanding - it won't work as it executed the if statement when the gem is build not when installed. Thus you'll get a different runtime dependency depending on the platform you're building the gem !

Answer (score 1):

You can create different gems for each platform. You can also create a single one that performs unique operations for each platform using a `case` statement in the main file. Here is an example for file inclusion that matches the operating system by checking the platform name against regular expressions:

```
def require_files(os)
  files[os].each { |file| require file }
end

case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /win32/
    require_files :win32
  when /linux/
    require_files :linux
  # and so on...
end
```

This, of course, can be generalized to any multi-platform task.

Answer (score 0):

Nominate that your gem is to be installed locally from a locally built gem.
The best way to reduce dependency pecking-ping-pong.
There should be a configuration option in gem to mandate this.
Have not checked to confirm existence of such.

MarkT